# TypeError: Cannot create property '_id' on number '1' when trying to submit to MondoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, dictionary

My code finds a subreddit and returns 25 new comments in a JSON format. I then convert it to a string and splice it by its spaces while also removing special characters. I then generate a dictionary that counts the frequency of words in each comment. Then I send the dictionary to my db.

The problem is I want to break down the objects and have every word be an entry or merge all the objects into one and sum the frequency of any repeated keys.

Here is an attempt to iterate through the keys:

```js
function insertData() {
  let words = new Array();
  let commentlist = r.getSubreddit('').getNewComments();
  let cleanData = async() => {
    let result = await (commentlist);
    return result;
  };

  cleanData().then(function(result) {
    for (i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
      let currentData = JSON.stringify(result[i].body).split(' ');
      for (j = 0; j <= currentData.length; j++) {
        if (currentData[j] != undefined) {
          words.push(currentData[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {
      words[i] = words[i].replace(/[?.,"'\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "", '');
      words[i] = words[i].replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ");
      words[i] = words[i].replace(/[0-9]/g, " ");
    }

  }).then(() => {
    var wordsMap = {};
    words.forEach(function(key) {
      if (wordsMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        wordsMap[key]++;
      } else {
        wordsMap[key] = 1;
      }
    });

    words = wordsMap;
    console.log(words);
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.DB_CONNECTION, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      const dbo = db.db("d");
      const messageTable = dbo.collection("x");
      for (var key in words) {
        messageTable.insertOne(words[key], function(err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("documents inserted");
        });
      }
    })
  });

}
```

But I get an error do to the last for loop even if I remove all numbers from my keys. The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot create property '_id' on number '1'

Now my question is would it be easier to merge the objects in my database and sort them by their frequency or separate them before or after inserting them into my database. How would I do this from where I am at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I misunderstood what `words[key]` did and was just accessing the value as opposed to submitting an object. I fixed this by creating an object an changing the function from `inserOne()` to `insertMany()`. The change takes place in the last for loop:

```js
MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            const dbo = db.db("mydb");
            const messageTable = dbo.collection("comments");
            for(var key in words){
                let myobj = 
                [{ 
                    word: key,
                    message: words[key]
                }];
                messageTable.insertMany(myobj, function(err, res){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("documents inserted");
                });
            }
        })
```